# Android App Login with navigation drawer cant click fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, authentication, navigation-drawer

I am new to Android, and developing a practice app using Navigation Drawer. I have a login wich is working fine, then I added the Navigation Drawer and I can´t get the fragments clickable when I run the app. I did do both separate for the first time and everything works there.

This is my MainActivity.

```
package com.startingandroid.registrationandlogin;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;   
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private Session session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
    session = new Session(MainActivity.this);

    if (!session.getLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    }

    private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    }

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        //Set fragment initially
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        //Set fragment initially

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Good Bye", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what you have shared, in the 
`public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {` method you need to implement fragment initiation code to replace the content fragment, similar to what has already been done for the case of the camera menu item, so for example if the menu item is for homepage, do

```
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment replacementFragment = null;
    String replacementTitle = null;
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            replacementFragment = new HomepageFragment();
            replacementTitle = "Home";
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, replacementFragment).commit();
            break;
       ...
```

Make sure you are using `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

**Edit:**
Here are the steps in summary:

1. Create navigation menu items(already done in your case)
2. Override `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` and check which
   menu item has been clicked, this is also already done in the if
   statement inside your activity.
3. Create a fragment to be called when its menu item is selected. (I
   think you are missing this part). A fragment consists of it's layout
   and a fragment class.
4. When the correct menu item is clicked, show the fragment by
   replacing    the content fragment with your fragment, this is what
   the above code    does. It initiates the new fragment called
   `HomepageFragment` and    sets it as the content for the
   `fragment_container`. So you need to    create a fragment called
   HomepageFragment

Also your use of switch case in the code pasted below does not look right, you don't have to use switch, just use the if statement you already have and replace the conditions with the name of your menu items, this may not be necessary also if you have not changed the ids of the menu items

You used the switch statement wrongly, try this:

```
   @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Check in your /res/menu/ folder in the menu xml file called `activity_main_drawer.xml` and ensure you have one entry with id nav_home, or rename one of the items there so that it can match the cascading if statement in the activity. Something like this

```
        <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:title="@string/homepageTitle" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response:) I did add it and edited like i thought i have to from my understandings first it gave me a error that a return is missing so i did that now i get a error : Unreachable statement  for this : MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment(); I will post the code if you need any more just let me know so i can post it thanks in advance

Comment: thanks again but i do have a mainfragment in my layout aswell as a java class so i guess in this case i dont youse the HomepageFragment but the MainFragment that i created right ?

Comment: and also did i place the code in the right postion ?

Comment: @DanielFrench No, I have edited your method to remove an unnecessary switch and a break statement that was skipping the important part, it should work now

Comment: It didnt work :( I pasted the code and it took me straight to the drawer so it skiped the login part and still nothing is clickable

Comment: So the right fragment showed up but was not clickable? That seems to be a problem with the layout items in that fragment.

Comment: appstart > splash screen> Login> Mainactivity (app drawer) and here is the problem i slide it out and back in but if i hit for instance Camera or any other fragment in there nothing is happining i created a toast on the logout fragment but as the otheres were ever i click nothing is going to happen

Comment: Check the edit I added in the answer above, and try adding breakpoints to the method and conditions to see which one is matched. It may be something as simple as a typo

Comment: https://youtu.be/83D81Soa14I here is a video of it I can register as well login but when I open the drawer and press on the fragments nothing happens

Comment: Please post how you did it and if I was any help also upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class main_drawer extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_drawer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment replacementFragment = null;
    String replacementTitle = null;
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            replacementFragment = new Fragment();
            replacementTitle = "Camera";
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, replacementFragment).commit();
            break;

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: nav_home is changed to nav_camera

Answer (score 0):

there was a good part of code missing as we can see

package com.startingandroid.registrationandlogin;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



Toolbar toolbar = null;
NavigationView navigationView = null;
private Session session;
public String data[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Set the fragment initially
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();



    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    session = new Session(MainActivity.this);

    if (!session.getLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    //How to change elements in the header programatically
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView emailText = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    emailText.setText("newemail@email.com");

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        //Set the fragment initially
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        LogoutFragment fragment = new LogoutFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        logoutUser();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```